# Can a convex/concave function be transformed to a concave/convex function in a generic way?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, transformation

My question is that let’s say I have a concave increasing function, can I transform it into a new convex increasing function? I know you can take log or exp of the function till it changes one to another, but I mean in a more generic and certain way.

Comment: What do you mean by transform? The question doesn't really make sense as stated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea, surely not what you intended. 
Negation flips about the horizontal, changing
concave to convex.
Reflecting in a vertical line $x=c$ then turns convex decreasing to
convex increasing.
Shifting vertically with constants retains these properties.

---

[image: ConcConv]

          

<sup>$3+x^2$ is concave increasing, $10-x^2$ is convex decreasing.
$10-(x-4)^2$ reflects around the vertical $x=4$.</sup>

---

Comment: The usual convention is to say a function is convex if any segment between two graph points lies above the graph; or, similarly, if the function's epigraph is a convex set. So $3+x^2$ is convex, not concave. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that $f$ is strictly increasing and concave it follows that it has an inverse $f^{-1}$ that is strictly increasing.

- $f^{-1}$ is convex because for all $x,y$ in the range of $f$ we have $u,v$ such that $x=f(u),y=f(v)$ and
  $$
  f^{-1}\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)=f^{-1}\Big(\frac{f(u)+f(v)}{2}\Big)\,.
  $$
  Note that
  $$
  f^{-1}\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)\le \frac{f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y)}{2}\,,
  $$
  which is the convexity of $f^{-1}\,,$
  is equivalent to
  $$
  \frac{x+y}{2}\le f\Big(\frac{f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y)}{2}\Big)\,,
  $$
  that is, to
  $$
  \frac{f(u)+f(v)}{2}\le f\Big(\frac{u+v}{2}\Big)\,,
  $$
  which is the concavity of $f$.

Comment: The graph of the inverse of an invertible function is symmmetric with the function respect to the diagonal $y=x$ so if  one of them is concave the other is convexe.